# How to use scoket.io in next js 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server, socket.io, socket.io-client

in React we have app to put in createServer(app)

in next.js how to deal with what we have to put inside createServer().

I think this is issue to resolve.

Solution of problem so that I can understand how to approach this.